# Keyboard overlaps Edit Text

Tags: android, scrollview, android-softkeyboard

Hello i have an activity which contains the following elements 
this is my xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="#dddddd">

 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="#dddddd">

  <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="title"
    android:textSize="@dimen/checkout_title"
    android:textColor="#858585"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" /> 

   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/pager"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="474dp"
  android:layout_below="@+id/title"
  android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

   <com.pockee.views.CirclePageIndicator android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/pager"
    app:pageColor="#858585"
    app:fillColor="#f19201" />

   <LinearLayout android:layout_below="@+id/indicator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:background="#80000000"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <TextView 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Value:"
      android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <EditText
      android:id="@+id/value1"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="40dp"
      android:background="@color/white"
      android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:inputType="number" />

     <TextView 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
      android:text="Value2:"
      android:textColor="@color/white" />

     <EditText
      android:id="@+id/value2"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="40dp"
      android:password="true"
      android:background="@color/white"
      android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:inputType="number" />

     <Button 
      android:id="@+id/btn"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
      android:text="OK"
      android:background="#f19100"
      android:textColor="@color/white"
      android:textStyle="bold" />

   </LinearLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>
   </ScrollView>
```

in my manifest i'm using

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible"
```

the problem is that the number keyboard overlaps edit text by 10 pixels

any ideas on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I see you have a relative layout wrapping your linear layout, yet both your linearLayout and relative layout have a margin of 10dp.  Try editing the inner value 'LinearLayout' margin to 0 or changing margin altogether i.e use bottom-margin:0 instead of margin and reloading.

Comment: i've removed all the margins and the result is the same

Comment: the problems is with background color of the edit text